# Most efficient way to decode Protobuf repeated field array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, protocol-buffers

I'm working with polygon coordinate arrays that are encoded in a .pbf file. For a multipolygon, the geometry object has a **Lengths** array with ordered values.

- The first represents the total number of shapes (a shape has an outer
  ring and optionally one or more inner rings).
- The second (and formulaically) successive values are counts of rings
  for each shape, e.g. a value of 2 means the next two items in the
  array are grouped with it.
- Subsequent values in each group contain counts of ring vertices.

For example, a geometry object that has 4 shapes: 1st has one hole, 2nd has none, 3rd has two holes, fourth has one hole has a Lengths array of [ 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 3 ]:

[image: lengths diagram]

My initial thought is to iterate through the array, using Skip and Take to get the values needed to 1) find each ring count value and 2) the number of vertices for each ring. Being new to Protobuf, I'm wondering if there's some more efficient pre-existing way to do this though.

```
var ringsVertexIndexList = new List<int>();

for (var index = 1; index < lengths.Count; index++)
{
    // Get the number of rings related to each shape
    var currentRingCount = lengths.Skip(index).First();

    for (var i = 1; i <= currentRingCount; i++)
    {
        var currentRing = lengths[index + i];

        ringsVertexIndexList.Add(currentRing);
    }

    // Advance index to end of current rings (incrementer will add 1 as it loops)
    index = index + currentRingCount;
}
```

Comment: Your iteration logic is reasonably efficient, **if** the encoding is already given.  But do you really need to encode in a single flat array? Can't you use hierarchical message structure?

Comment: I tried searching on HMS, especially related to protobuf and didn't turn up anything helpful. So I'm not sure how to proceed. The decodeMultiPolygon method in https://github.com/jeo/jeo/blob/195eb508de817b1e477a34a523b17803d64f42c5/format/geobuf/src/main/java/io/jeo/geobuf/GeobufReader.java seems usable as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and diagramming the problem (I'm a visual person), I came up with:

```
var lengths = feature.Geometry.Lengths.ToList().ConvertAll(x => (int) x); // int32

if (lengths.Count > 0)
{
    var coordsListStart = 0;
    var lengthsCursor = 1;

    var multipolyList = new List<Polygon>();

    while (lengthsCursor < lengths.Count)
    {
        var ringsCount = lengths[lengthsCursor];

        lengthsCursor++;

        var polygonLineStringsList = new List<LineString>();

        for (var move = 0; move < ringsCount; move++)
        {
            var ringVertexCount = lengths[lengthsCursor];

            // ring processing
            var coordsList = encodedCoordsSubList.GetRange(coordsListStart, ringVertexCount);

            var lineStr = BuildLineString(coordsList, true);

            polygonLineStringsList.Add(lineStr);

            // update start to new position
            coordsListStart += ringVertexCount;

            lengthsCursor++;
        }

        multipolyList.Add(new Polygon(polygonLineStringsList));
    }

    geoJsonFeature.Geometry = new MultiPolygon(multipolyList);
}
```

This may not be the most efficient, but it has worked with all my test sets just fine. Worth noting that the encodedCoordsSubList is a `List<List<int>>` that contains all the x, y, z values.